# how to get rid of the attached code in the url in facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have used facebook sdk php for my facebook. All the login process is working fine. but the only problem is I am getting the code after login in the browser url like:

http://www.xyz.com/home?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I just want to get rid of this code. 
Can any body help me on this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    header("location: http://www.xyz.com/home");
}
```

I did the same thing a few days ago to get rid of it..